# EventGrid trigger / handler in WebJobs

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-eventgrid

Straight to the point: is there a way to handle EventGrid events in WebJobs?

What I've got so far is:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
                        .UseEnvironment(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"))
                        .ConfigureWebJobs(config =>
                        {
                            config.AddEventGrid();
                            config.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                            // config.AddTimers();
                        })
```

Which registers the EventGrid extension, I also have a handler (class with a method using `EventGridTrigger` attribute).

When I run it I can see in logs that the extension is initialised:
[image]

And the host seems to be aware of the function as well:
[image]

This is my function / handler so far (not very helpful presumably):

```
public class EventGridHandler
    {
        public Task Run([EventGridTrigger] CloudEvent ev)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Few questions that are rather obvious:

1. How to configure the endpoint?
2. Is there anything else I will need to make it work? (assuming that it's possible to make it work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **It's not possible**

Longer answer: In order to expose `EventGrid` extension one needs an implementation for `IWebhookProvider` and the only implementation I could find lives in Azure Functions Host

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck on the same problem. My solution was simple:

- create an storage account queue
- subscribe the gridevent to deliver into the queue
- use QueueTrigger in WebJob

Hopefully they allow us soon to set a configuration for the receiving part without an additional stop in a queue.

Comment: Exactly what I've done, thanks.